# Delete unused tables and fields in django

Tags: django, oracle

I'm working on a Django project version 2.2 using Oracle SQL Database. In this database there are some tables that are not managed by Django models and I want to delete these. Because there are nearly 1800 tables in this database, I need to find a way to detect these by some sort of script or query. Also in some tables there are some fields that are always null for any records. Actually, I have got many unusable fields in my database.

How can I detect and remove these fields and tables using Django or Oracle SQL?

I ran a sql query to list all tables and compare it to output of django command `apps.get_models()` but it didn't help.

Comment: The Oracle data dictionary won't have any idea which tables are part of your Django model, so unless there's an easy way to identify them by something in the name or some other automatically captured metadata, you'll likely have to make the comparison manually, as you've apparently tried to do. The same will go for unused columns - just because something is empty doesn't mean it isn't *valid*, so you'll have to manually review those as well.

Comment: Maybe you could utilize the `python manage.py dumpdata` command. Let's say your django knows about the table `Cars` because you created a model called `Cars` but your django does not know about the table `Boats` because you don't have a model called `Boats`. Then the dumpdata command will dump the `Cars` but not the `Boats`. Therefore you got rid of the "unused" `Boats`.